# Is there way to make split windows of different color or some how to easily spot which window is active?

Tags: vim

I used `:sp somefile_name` to split vim into 2 horizontal split.
But then i often type into the wrong window, because the color is the same, hard to notice which is the windows that my current cursor is on..
Is there way to  solve this issue ?
Thx

Comment: You can make the status bar a different color for a window that's active... Plug-ins such as [`itchyny/lightline.vim`](https://github.com/itchyny/lightline.vim) implement that by default. Maybe just adopt that plug-in?

Comment: [airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) also changes bar color for active window. That's what I use. Highly recommend.

Comment: I have script that changes status bar color when in edit and replace mode. But it does not indicate which window is active. I don't like to use plugin.. also because i have not learn how to use it yet.

Comment: @AJ-Williams1 what is airline ? is it a plug in ?  i rather like script..

Comment: Just with if there is way to make caret red color or something that is high contrast from the black background.  then, won't need to do something to status bar color.

Comment: nevermind about this. I have mapped vertical cursor line to a function key. works like a charm.

Comment: how to close this thread ?